ReadTimeout Exception When Making Request to VirusTotal API
I’m encountering a ReadTimeout  exception when attempting to access the VirusTotal API using the requests  library in Python. Interestingly, I can access VirusTotal via a browser (Chrome) without issues, but I receive a timeout error in Edge. Here’s the traceback I received:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.virustotal.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)

Code Snippet:
Here's a simplified version of the code that causes the issue:
import requests

def get_ip_report_vt(ip):
    url = f"https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/{ip}"
    headers = {
        "x-apikey": "YOUR_API_KEY"
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

# Process IP list
def process_ip_list(input_csv_file, output_csv_file):
    ip = "8.8.8.8"  # Example IP
    vt_score, vt_country, vt_organization = get_ip_report_vt(ip)
    # Further processing...

process_ip_list("input.csv", "output.csv")

Here's more detailed script:
import requests
import csv
import time

# API keys for VirusTotal and AbuseIPDB
VIRUSTOTAL_API_KEYS = [
    'YOUR_VIRUSTOTAL_API_KEY'  # Replace with your actual API key
]

ABUSEIPDB_API_KEYS = [
    'YOUR_ABUSEIPDB_API_KEY'  # Replace with your actual API key
]

# Round-robin index counters
vt_key_index = 0
abuseipdb_key_index = 0

# Function to get the next API key
def get_next_api_key(api_keys, index):
    key = api_keys[index % len(api_keys)]
    index += 1
    return key, index

# Function to query VirusTotal for IP report
def get_ip_report_vt(ip):
    global vt_key_index
    api_key, vt_key_index = get_next_api_key(VIRUSTOTAL_API_KEYS, vt_key_index)
    
    url = f"https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/{ip}"
    headers = {"x-apikey": api_key}
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an error for HTTP codes 4xx/5xx
        data = response.json()
        return data['data']['attributes']['reputation'], data['data']['attributes']['country']
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"VirusTotal Error for IP {ip}: {e}")
        return None, None

# Function to query AbuseIPDB for IP report
def get_ip_report_abuseipdb(ip):
    global abuseipdb_key_index
    api_key, abuseipdb_key_index = get_next_api_key(ABUSEIPDB_API_KEYS, abuseipdb_key_index)
    
    url = "https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check"
    headers = {'Key': api_key, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    params = {'ipAddress': ip}
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        return data['data']['abuseConfidenceScore'], data['data']['countryCode']
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"AbuseIPDB Error for IP {ip}: {e}")
        return None, None

# Main function to process IPs
def process_ip_list(input_csv, output_csv):
    with open(input_csv, 'r') as infile, open(output_csv, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(['IP', 'VT Score', 'VT Country', 'AbuseIPDB Score', 'AbuseIPDB Country'])

        next(reader)  # Skip header
        for row in reader:
            ip = row[0]
            vt_score, vt_country = get_ip_report_vt(ip)
            abuse_score, abuse_country = get_ip_report_abuseipdb(ip)
            writer.writerow([ip, vt_score, vt_country, abuse_score, abuse_country])
            time.sleep(1)  # Respect rate limits

# Example usage
process_ip_list('ip_list.csv', 'ip_report_list.csv')

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Check API Key: Verified that my API key is valid and active.
Network Issues:


I tried accessing VirusTotal on different browsers, and it works fine on Chrome but not on Edge, which shows ERR_TIMED_OUT.
I ran a ping test, but it resulted in "Request timed out."
Changed DNS settings to Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), which allowed Edge to access VirusTotal, but I still face the same timeout issue in my code.


Firewall/Proxy: turn off the firewall and proxy settings and still have the issue.

Additional Context:

It used to be that sometimes it would work and sometimes it wouldn't. And now it's just stop working.
ABUSEIPDB API works when I wrote the code for only ABUSEIPDB.
before it used to go to 100 IP then stop and shows an error then after sometimes it would work. but now it's just won't work. I used difference Key because I run out of the 500 request and didn't worked.

Does anyone have suggestions for resolving this network-related issue or troubleshooting further?

The timeout is a server-side issue. Also, your code vt_score, vt_country, vt_organization = get_ip_report_vt(ip) will induce a ValueError exception

I deleted the VirusTotal from the history of the browser and it worked.
